# What does ref=True/False parameter do in gevent sleep?

Tags: python, gevent

The docs to `gevent.sleep()` function say the following about its `ref=True/False` parameter:

```
def sleep(seconds=0, ref=True):
    """
    If *ref* is False, the greenlet running ``sleep()`` will not prevent :func:`gevent.wait`
    from exiting.
    """
```

Does anyone know what this means? I've made several attempts to google some more detailed explanation on what does `ref` parameter do, but, weirdly enough, all the explanation I could find on the internet was this same sentence and no more details.

What are the possible circumstances when it makes sense to pass `ref=False` (as you can see in function definition it's `True` by default)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to not do anything right now.  This took a lot of digging through the code, but basically what happens is the following chain of events when you call the `sleep` function.

- `sleep` is imported from `gevent.hub`.
- In the code for `gevent.hub.sleep` we see `loop.timer(seconds, ref)`.
- `loop` comes from `hub.loop`, which comes from `hub = _get_hub_noargs()`, `_get_hub_noargs` is imported from `gevent._hub_local`

The trail gets a little cold here, but searching through the code for references to `ref` and `timer` turns up a few classes of interest.

- `gevent.libev.timer` is a the class that is called in `loop.timer` above.  It is a subclass of `gevent.libev.watcher`.
- `gevent.libev.watcher` is where we finally see a reference to what is happening with `ref`.
- `gevent.libev.timer` also makes reference to a `loop` object (more on that later).

Depending on how `ref` is set certain actions do or do not occur on classes inheriting from `watcher`.  In particular, it will call `self.loop.ref()` or `self.loop.unref()`.  As seen here:

```
class watcher(_base.watcher):

    ...

    def _watcher_ffi_ref(self):
        if self._flags & 2: # we've told libev we're not referenced
            self.loop.ref()
            self._flags &= ~2

    def _watcher_ffi_unref(self):
        if self._flags & 6 == 4:
            # We're not referenced, but we haven't told libev that
            self.loop.unref()
            self._flags |= 2 # now we've told libev

    ...
```

Looking at the code for `gevent.libuv.loop` we find the `loop` class.  However, when you look at the `ref` and `unref` methods, they don't do anything.

```
@implementer(ILoop)
class loop(AbstractLoop):

    ...

    def ref(self):
        pass

    def unref(self):
        # XXX: Called by _run_callbacks.
        pass

    ...
```

I might be missing something entirely, but as far as I can tell, these are methods that will be implemented in the future.

Comment: If you are correct and ref parameter indeed does nothing at all then maybe this is the reason why nothing at all can be found on the internet about it...

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that yet =/ Thank you for looking into it anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I believe setting `ref` to `False` allows not blocking the `wait/joinall` from exiting.

Consider the following program:

```py
import gevent
import gevent.event
import signal
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s")


def start_loop_with_long_non_blocking_sleep(stop):
    while not stop.is_set():
        logging.info("Every 5 seconds, not blocking exit")
        gevent.sleep(seconds=5, ref=True)


def start_loop_with_short_blocking_sleep(stop):
    while not stop.is_set():
        logging.info("Every second, blocking exit")
        gevent.sleep(seconds=1, ref=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop = gevent.event.Event()

    def handle_signal(signal):
        logging.info(f"Handling signal {signal}")
        stop.set()

    for sig in [signal.SIGINT]:
        gevent.signal_handler(sig, handle_signal, sig)

    logging.info("Starting")
    gevent.spawn(start_loop_with_long_non_blocking_sleep, stop)
    gevent.spawn(start_loop_with_short_blocking_sleep, stop)

    gevent.wait()
    logging.info("Done")
```

Here is the output:

```
› python3 thing.py
2022-12-14 18:32:02,699 Starting
2022-12-14 18:32:02,700 Every 5 seconds, not blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:02,700 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:03,703 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:04,705 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:05,705 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:06,706 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:07,703 Every 5 seconds, not blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:07,707 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:32:08,710 Every second, blocking exit
^C2022-12-14 18:32:08,757 Handling signal 2                 <-- I pressed Ctrl+C
2022-12-14 18:32:09,716 Done
```

As you can see from the last timestamp, upon receiving `SIGTERM`, the program has waited on the sleep of the shorter loop (which has `ref=True`), but did not wait the full 5 seconds of the longer loops' sleep (which has `ref=False`)

This would not be the case if the longer loop had `ref=True`:

```
› python3 thing.py
2022-12-14 18:33:08,716 Starting
2022-12-14 18:33:08,716 Every 5 seconds, not blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:33:08,716 Every second, blocking exit
2022-12-14 18:33:09,719 Every second, blocking exit
^C2022-12-14 18:33:10,176 Handling signal 2         <-- I pressed Ctrl+C
2022-12-14 18:33:13,720 Done                        <-- Waited full 5 seconds since the
                                                        last iteration of the longer loop!
```

`gevent.sleep(..., ref=False)` can be useful, for example, if one needed to periodically print some statistics about program execution.